# How do I link a javascript file to one of multiple html files within an express SPA?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

[current project layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaCk9.png)

I am very new to Express and making SPA's. Im trying to link JavaScript file to my contact.html file in order to send an email to an email address when the contact form is submitted. For some reason I cant seem to find the right place to put the code and I keep getting an error.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXPdq.png)

this is what my server.js looks like.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.use('/static', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'static')));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => console.log('Server running...'));
```

it is extremely possible that I am missing something or not explaining this properly so my apologies in advance.

Im not sure if i need to write the code in a new javascript file or an existing one, or if what im trying to do is even possible. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your error message is caused in index.js.  We can't help with that error without seeing the code for that particular file.  And, your question doesn't include enough detail on what you're actually trying to do and what code you've tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: A Javascript file is included in an HTML file with a `<script src="some URL"></script>` tag that points to a URL where the file can be loaded by the browser.  Or, they can be dynamically retrieved by Javascript using an XMLHttpRequest or `fetch()` call from within your web page Javascript.  Beyond that, I'm not sure what else you're asking.